# How to consume multipart/form data request in C# mvc 4 webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a web service for file upload. When I call this webservice I can't find multipart-form data request.

If I call this webservice without a file then it will working fine.

My code is:

Interface code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST",   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetStream")]
void GetStream(Stream fileUpload);
```

---

Message contract code:

```
public void GetStream(Stream fileUpload)
{
    // here I find null fileUpload object
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Request.Files variable.

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
      var postedFile = Request.Files[file];
      postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles") + pelicula.Id);
}
```